# What is an `invalid token in class` error?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been using a tutorial guide for the game I'm making to figure out the basics and I ran into 2 errors while coding the collisions:

1. Invalid token "{" in class, struct, or interface member of declaration and
2. Type or namespace definition, or end of file expected.

Here is the code:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerCollision : MonoBehaviour
{
 public PlayerMovement movement;
 {
  void OnCollisionEnter (Collision collisonInfo)
  {
   if (collisonInfo.collider.tag == "Obstacles")
    movement.enabled = false;
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: You don't need the second curly braces.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have too many curly braces:

```
public class PlayerCollision : MonoBehaviour
{
    public PlayerMovement movement;
    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collisonInfo)
    {
        if (collisonInfo.collider.tag == "Obstacles")
            movement.enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: The solutions are causing more errors, some of the errors re even in another file of my code editor. (PlayerMovement), but when I add curly brackets after public PlayerMovement movement; it shortens the errors to 2, being the ones I listed before.

Comment: I found the error!  All of my scripts duplicated themselves and then got confused because there was an identical script doing the same thing.  Thanks for the help, though!